# When does AT&T Note 4 receive Lollipop?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung, stock-android, samsung-galaxy-note-4

**When does Lollipop hit AT&T Note 4?**
I have read many articles that the Note 4 was going to receive Lollipop late January. But still no updates. I believe the Galaxy S5 AT&T has Lollipop.
Any one have any ideas what the release date is?

Comment: @AndrewT. No it's not a duplicate AT&T has its own basically creation of Lollipop. AT&T locks your phone kind of like a iPhone. For instance sprint has the Note 4 but their OS runs solely on the base OS from Samsung,(Samsung makes it look like their own os I know it's Powered by Android) So I wanted to know when the AT&T Note 4 Lollipop OS comes out. I seen those articles before.

Comment: We don't allow individual questions about every possible device getting every possible update, they are all collected into one.

Comment: @MatthewRead its a question that lots of others want to know as well. I can't be the only one! AT&T barely release info.

Comment: Nobody is saying that you're the only one who wants to know this. I don't know where you got that idea. What we're saying is that we consolidate all of the upgrade information into one place, because otherwise the site would simply get **flooded** with questions about stuff like this. There would be literally *hundreds* of "When will [some device] get [some update]?" questions. When (or if) AT&T announces something, it will be added to the list with all the others.